# Add  Icon in a Column of CellTable in GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt2, uibinder

With all the values in textcoloumn.

I want to add image cell.

**I don't want use Gwt-Ext or Smart client.**

My code

```
private CellTable<FDocument> getDocumentTable() {
        if (documentTable == null) {
            documentTable = new CellTable<FDocument>();
            documentTable.setSize("600px", "300px");
            documentTable.addColumn(nameColumnD, "NAME");
            documentTable.addColumn(sizeColumnD, "SIZE");
            documentTable.addColumn(modified_by_ColumnD, "MODIFIED BY");
            documentTable.addColumn(dateColumnD, "MODIFIED ON");
            documentTable.addColumn(majorVersion, "Major Version");


        }
        return documentTable;
    }

TextColumn<FDocument> nameColumnD = new TextColumn<FDocument>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(FDocument object) {
                return object.getName();
            }
        };          
        TextColumn<FDocument> sizeColumnD = new TextColumn<FDocument>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(FDocument object) {
                return object.getSize();                            
            }
        };

..// similarly all the coloumn.
```

I want to add to image Cell. How to do it.

---

**edited**

```
ImageCell imageCell=new ImageCell();
        Column<FDocument,String> iconColumn = new Column<FDocument, String>(imageCell){

            @Override
            public String getValue(FDocument object) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return object.getImageUrl(object);
            }

        };
```

in FDocument Class

public String getImageUrl(FilenetDocument object){

```
            if(object.getMimeType().equals("text/plain")){
        return "url(Txt16.gif)";
    }else{
        if(object.getMimeType()=="application/x-filenet-publishtemplate"){
            return "url(PublishTemplate16.gif)";
        }else{
            if(object.getMimeType()=="application/x-filenet-filetype-msg"){
                return "url(Msg16.gif)";
            }else{
                if(object.getMimeType()=="application/x-filenet-workflowdefinition"){
                    return "url(WorkflowDefinition16.gif)";
                }else{
                    if(object.getMimeType()=="application/msword"){
                        return "url(Doc16.gif)";
                    }else{
                        return "url(Txt16.gif)";
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Override `render` method which can be used to add any type of `HTML` content as Column in CellTable

```
TextColumn<FDocument> iconColumn = new TextColumn<FDocument>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(FDocument object) {
            return "";                          
        }

    @Override
        protected void render(Context context, SafeHtml value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        if (value != null) {
          sb.appendHtmlConstant("<p style=\"textalign:center;\"><img src=\"icon.gif\"\></p>"); 

        }
       }    
    };
```

Comment: there are many document like pdf doc. their respesctive icons are saved in war folder.I am able to display all the values of document except the icon.
i know the mime type of each document.
plz chk the edited part of the code.

Comment: I dont know how render wil help me to make icon .

and there return is ""; and when  render is called.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `getImageUrl()`, the return is a css style, not path to an image...

So either implement a new Cell which render with the style you provide, or use a [ImageResourceCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ImageResourceCell.html) with your static icons, or try the render method provided by [Hardik Mishra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10416986/426350) but update `getImageUrl()` to return a PATH to an image.